# Variables containing dates changes value without being changed

Tags: javascript

I am working with a "from" and a "to" date.

Today they would be:

from == 3rd May

to == 10th May

In order to remember them after my for-loop I put them into

```
let fromMemory = from;

let toMemory = to;
```

But after the loop fromMemory has changed to 11th May???

I do not set it to 11th of May anywhere - how can this happen?? (and can this be avoided somehow?)

```
let from = new Date();
from.setHours(0,0,0,0);
from = new Date(from.setDate(from.getDate() - 7));
let fromMemory = from;
let to = new Date();
to.setHours(0,0,0,0);
let toMemory = to;
let dayArr = [""];
let cnt = 1;
for (let day = from; day <= to; day.setDate(day.getDate() + 1)) {
    let d = day;
    let m = d.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' });
    dayArr[cnt] = d.getDate() + " " + m;
    cnt++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write this:
`let fromMemory = from;`

`fromMemory` and `from` are 2 references on the same Javascript object. If you modify one, it will also modify the other.

If you want to make them independent, you have to do a clone like this:

`let fromMemory = new Date(from);`

Comment: Jep that worked.  Just strange it modified all objects equal to the one. But nice to know that it do and how to get around it.